# onChange not firing in a drop down listing in Safari, works in IE, FF, Chrome & Opera

Tags: javascript, html

I created a drop down listing that automatically fires using the onChange event when clicking on an item in the list. This works for IE, FF, Chrome & Opera but doesn't fire in Safari.

I have multiple drop down listing by year on the same page so the code below is an exert from one year hence the 2011 at the end of the id.

The domain below is an example and not my real domain.

JavaScript

```
    var issue;
       function selectMagazine2011(id){
          issue = document.getElementById(id).value;
             if (issue!=0){
                mywindow = window.open("http://www.domain.com.au/2011/magazine_"+issue+"/index.html","new","resizable=1,scrollbars=1");
                mywindow.focus();
             }
       }
```

HTML

```
    <div class="year">
      <label>2011:
        <select name="magazine2011" id="magazine2011" onchange="selectMagazine2011('magazine2011')">
          <option value="0" selected="selected">Select an Issue</option>
          <option value="Issue_4_2011">Issue 4 2011</option>
          <option value="Issue_3_2011">Issue 3 2011</option>
          <option value="Issue_2_2011">Issue 2 2011</option>
          <option value="Issue_1_2011">Issue 1 2011</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please set up a http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine in my Safari. I suspect you have your script in a `DOMReady` or `window.onload` handler? In this case, you need to define your function as

```
...
window.selectMagazine2011 = function(id) {
    ...
```

to make it available globally.

Comment: would I add this before the function selectMagazine2011(id).

Comment: This line should replace the function definition line `function selectMagazine2011(id){`.